# How to change the color and size of points in ggdist::stats_dots function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, ggdist

I am trying to visualize a scatterplot graph using ggdist and ggplot. I was able to get the plot to work, but I am trying to changed the color and the size of the points, and currently am not able to do that. I would like all points to be one color (like "blue" or "red"), and know where to change the size of the points.

```
    data <- data.frame(type = c('fruit', 'root', 'fruit', 'root'),
                         food = c('apple', 'taro', 'banana', 'potato'),
                         weight = c(2, 4, 3, 2))


ggplot(data, aes(x = data[,1], y = data[,3])) +
          ggdist::stat_dots(side = "both") +
          theme_classic() +
          theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20 ), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20 ), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 30),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 20)) +
          stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 18, size = 6, color="black")  + 
          stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun = median, size = 15, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
          labs(title = "title", subtitle = "sub title"  ,x = "x title", y = "y title",
               caption = "caption") +
          scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 4.5))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Edited to add reproducible data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the arguments `fill` and `dotsize` to change the color and size of the dots like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = data[,1], y = data[,3])) +
  ggdist::stat_dots(side = "both", fill = "blue", dotsize = 0.2) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20 ), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20 ), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 30),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 20)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 18, size = 6, color="black")  + 
  #stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun = median, size = 15, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  labs(title = "title", subtitle = "sub title"  ,x = "x title", y = "y title",
       caption = "caption") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 4.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>